$T(1) = \mu$ and $T(n + 1) = F(a_n)$ where F(x) = $\frac{2*(x^2 + 34)}{x + 18}$ - examine convergence
$$
\left.\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{T}\left(1\right) & = & \mu \not= 18
\\[1mm]
\operatorname{T}\left(n + 1\right) & = & \operatorname{F}\left(T(n)\right)
\end{array}\right\}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad
\operatorname{F}\left(x\right) =
\,{2*(x^{2} + 34) \over x + 18}
$$
and I need to examine the convergence.
My attempt:

So I assume its a converging series.
I am finding the fixed points ( which are the potential limits ):
$$
\mbox{They are}\ 9 \pm \sqrt{13}
$$
Then I need to examine the monotony with
$\operatorname{T}\left(n + 1\right) - \operatorname{T}\left(n\right)$.

But I don't know how to do it and how to proceed.
Any help ?.

What is $a_n$ ? Perhaps you mean $T(n+1) = F(T(n))$ ?

A series is an infinite sum like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$. Do you mean “a converging sequence”?

You found a fixed point, $f$. Take a value $x$ near it, $|f-x| = \epsilon$. Apply a recurrence, and check if the resulting distance from $f$ is $\le \epsilon$ (we are converging) or $\ge \epsilon$ (we are diverging). Monotonicity is mostly irrelevant.

You need to examine the convergence of what?
